# Ionic CORS Problem only if adding custom header to request (Spring boot backend)

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, ionic-framework, cors

I know... The CORS problematic is a well discussed topic. After searching for hours and hours for the solution of my problem, I ask you now for help :)

I have an ionic angular app and a spring boot application for my backend. The backend is hosted on a public server (with a domain) and with a letsencrypt ssl encryption.

All was working fine until I've added a custom header. I receive for each request a cors error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.BACKEND_URL.com:5000/healthstatus' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've added the custom header argument with an interceptor like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs"; 
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";

@Injectable() export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { } 

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   console.log('####: interceptor: addHeader'); 
   request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer TEST-TOKEN` } });
   return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

On the controller I've added also the CrossOrigin annotation

```
@CrossOrigin
@Controller
```

Only when I edit the header I receive the CORS error. Can you give me an advice? Is there another way to add my token to the request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution!

In Spring boot I'am using a "HandlerInterceptor". This interceptor allows only requests which has my token in the header.

When the browser asks the server for some cors info, the browser sends a **OPTIONS**-call to the backend server. This option call was also be rejected and thus not able to retrieve the allowed methods/headers/origins...

My code looks like this

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) { 
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //I've changed the 'Authorization' header to 'token' (at the end of the following codeline) 
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "AuthID,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,token");
    //After that, continue without checking if the request is correct
    return true; 
} else {
    //check if the request-header contains my token...
}
```

If you have implemented the spring boot security you should adjust the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```